# Await is only allowed within async functions - webpack, redux thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im trying to do an async call with redux thunk in webpack but get a weird message - 'await' is only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules

```
export const createPost = (post) => async => (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.createPost(post);

    dispatch({ type: "CREATE", payload: data })
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}
```

Initial webpack config

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: [
    "regenerator-runtime/runtime",
    path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_module/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|j?g|svg|gif)?$/,
        use: "file-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
};
```

I tried to change the webpack config by adding the plugin "@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await" to sort it but it gives me a different error now, I dont think I added it correctly.
Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
plugins: [

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
// test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           experiments: …
         }
       })
     ]
```

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: [
    "regenerator-runtime/runtime",
    path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
  ],
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_module/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|j?g|svg|gif)?$/,
        use: "file-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
};
```

Comment: you don't have a top level await, so that isn't the problem .... this code: `(post) => async => (dispatch) => {` is a function that returns a function that returns a function, and the fact that the middle function takes an argument you named `async` looks like it may be the issue .... did you mean `(post) => async (dispatch) => {`

Comment: `async => (dispatch) =>` should be `async (dispatch) =>`

Comment: Thankyou that did the trick, it was just the extra arrow function I failed to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there's an issue with how you declared your function, this is what you have:

```
export const createPost = (post) => async => (dispatch) => { 
 ...
}
```

I think what you need is

```
export const createPost = post => async (dispatch) => {
 ...
}
```

the problem is that the function that's actually doing the async action is this:

```
(dispatch) => { }
```

but you're putting the async keyword on a wrapper arrow function one level up:

```
async => (dispatch) => { ... }
```

I have not looked at your webpack config though, so not sure if there's an issue there too

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I just had an extra arrow which i failed to see that you specified.